# Loading XML file to display vs converting XML to MySQL and then display?

Tags: mysql, xml, performance

I am starting to work on a project that deals with XML configuration files. This web application will be something used by end customers to display how their devices are configured. These XML files will be thousands of lines per config file.

With PHP I can easily read the XML file and then do what I need to with the data.

Performance wise is reading the data straight from the XML file going to be faster/better vs converting the data to a MySQL database and then reading from the database?

I can always cache the processed/parsed XML for use so I don't have to constantly read the XML file again.

I want to build this with the possibility that this project could take off really well and have lots of people sharing their configurations.

Answer (score 0):

That depends mostly on the size of your xml files. Parsing a big amount of xml is for sure slower than querying mysql for some values, which are stored and sorted into tables already. For small xml-snippets, reading them directly from filesystem won't harm performance, but you might get in trouble with concurrent read/write access to xml-files (by different users e.g.).

So in the long run, I'd always go for the database solution. It 'scales' much better to whatever data you throw at/pull from it and concurrent accesses won't give you headaches.